# Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width, : unable to start device PNG

Tags: r, x11

I am tyring to generate png() with following command

png("test")
but i am getting following error.

**Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  : 
  unable to start device PNG**

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"

Note: When i login as root i don't get above error.

```
> capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE
```

i used options(bitmapType='cairo') also still same pblm. I rebuild R with dependency on but still same pblm. May i know how can i fix this issue.

Comment: Which OS? On OS-X you need to install xquartz.

Comment: I am working on ubunut. One more thing when i login as root i can generate png while as user i get above error.

Comment: If you are on ubuntu you should not install R from source. Just `apt-get install r-base-dev`.